# `docker service update` from remote server with cert

Tags: security, docker, certificate, docker-compose, docker-machine

I want to update my `docker stack` automatically from my CI server but I don't figure out how to configure credentials to be able to drive docker from an external host.

I have enabled experimental mode on my server and it works fine in local with docker-machine.

My deploy script look like this:

```
echo $DOCKER_CERT > cert.pem # which other file ?

OPTS=" --tlsverify --host $DOCKER_DEPLOY_HOST --tlscert cert.pem" # which other args ???

docker $OPTS pull $REPO_IMAGE
docker $OPTS service update multiverse-prod_api
```

Is there a way (or planned in future version) to achieve this with just an ssh key ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the docker server with a self signed cert, and then configure the client with a client cert signed from the same ca. The steps to create the certificates and configure the server and client are described by docker [in their documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/).